# SortedSet is unsorted after fetching from memcache

Tags: ruby, memcached, sortedset

From a Rake task I write a `SortedSet` to (mem)cache:

```
#<SortedSet: {"australian", "garagerock", "hiphop", "indie", "lofi", "skatepunk", "surf", "twopiece"}>
```

Then when I load this from (mem)cache the result is unsorted:

```
#<SortedSet: {"twopiece", "indie", "australian", "lofi", "garagerock", "skatepunk", "surf", "hiphop"}>
```

I guess I can just instantiate a new `SortedSet` with the unsorted result, but this doesn't seem like the correct behaviour though. Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: How do you serialize it memcached? Are you using any gem?

Comment: Yes I use Dalli and Rails.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue with no success, can you post the code you are using to store and load the `SortedSet`?